# create new column in dataframe consisting of integers found in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am extracting data from AutoCAD using ezdxf. When the values are placed in a data frame the data type is object. There will always be two columns however, either column could contain a integer or a string. It will always occur that on a row one of the columns will contain an integer and the other will contain a string.

The goal is to separate the data into two columns that contain the int values and the other the str. The int is a value for the string so the sort order does matter.

I have tried using .isdigit() to get true/false and then use if true copy checked columns value to new column. I have also tried to use a lambda function, but can't seem to get that to work either.

```
sdf3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['1', '2'])
# Loop to populate Data frame
# then after it is populated attempt to group data
print(sdf3.to_string())
sdf3.loc[:, 'first'] = sdf3.loc[:, '1'].astype(str).str.strip().str.isdigit()
sdf3.loc[:, 'second'] = sdf3.loc[:, '2'].astype(str).str.strip().str.isdigit()
sdf3['S_QTY'] = sdf3.apply(lambda x: x['1'] if x['first'].astype(str).str.contains('True') else 
                           x['2'], axis=1)
print(sdf3.to_string())

       1       2
0      4    CL-1
1   CL-4       1
2   CL-2      15
3   CL-5       1
4  RBC-1      16
5   CL-8       4

       1       2  first  second
0      4    CL-1   True   False
1   CL-4       1  False    True
2   CL-2      15  False    True
3   CL-5       1  False    True
4  RBC-1      16  False    True
5   CL-8       4  False    True
```

Comment: If the str value per row never starts with a digit, then sorting could be good enough, so `df[:] = np.sort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1)` or create a new dataframe

Comment: @Ben.T that works for this situation, I didn't consider sorting. Thanks. If you submit an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Swap values with the help of a boolean mask:

```
m = df['1'].str.isdigit()

df.loc[m, '1'], df.loc[m, '2'] = df.loc[m, '2'], df.loc[m, '1']
print(df)

# Output
       1   2
0   CL-1   4
1   CL-4   1
2   CL-2  15
3   CL-5   1
4  RBC-1  16
5   CL-8   4
```

Obviously, you can convert the last column to int with `df['2'] = df['2'].astype(int)`